# Groovy Swing buider fileChooser

Tags: groovy, swingbuilder

I am trying to use groovy swing builder's fileChooser with no luck. 
When I copy the following example from groovy website:

```
def openExcelDialog  = SwingBuilder.fileChooser(dialogTitle:"Choose an excel file", 
                               id:"openExcelDialog", fileSelectionMode :         JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY, 
                               //the file filter must show also directories, in order to be able to look into them
                               fileFilter: [getDescription: {-> "*.xls"}, accept:{file-> file ==~ /.*?\.xls/ || file.isDirectory() }] as FileFilter) {
```

}

But I got an error message:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static groovy.swing.SwingBuilder.fileChooser() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, ConsoleScript19$_run_closure1) values
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use the fileChooser like that outside a SwingBuilder.  Instead, you need to just use a normal, non-swingBuilder JFileChooser.  Here's a complete working example:

```
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter
import javax.swing.JFileChooser

def openExcelDialog = new JFileChooser(
                            dialogTitle: "Choose an excel file",
                            fileSelectionMode: JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY, 
                            //the file filter must show also directories, in order to be able to look into them
                            fileFilter: [getDescription: {-> "*.xls"}, accept:{file-> file ==~ /.*?\.xls/ || file.isDirectory() }] as FileFilter)

openExcelDialog.showOpenDialog()
```

Note that the `new JFileChooser` just ends with the closing parentheses - there's no trailing closure.

Answer (score 3):

OverZealous' solution fails with NPE.

```
Exception in thread "Basic L&F File Loading Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getTextLength(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.reset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matcher(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.matchRegex(InvokerHelper.java:335)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.matchRegex(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:722)
    at ExcelChooser2$_run_closure2.doCall(ExcelChooser2.groovy:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:884)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at FileFilter_groovyProxy.accept(Script1.groovy:7)
    at javax.swing.JFileChooser.accept(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run0(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel$LoadFilesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Solution:**

OLD: `fileFilter: [getDescription: {-> "*.xls"}, accept:{file -> file ==~ /.*?\.xls/  || file.isDirectory() }] as FileFilter`

NEW: `fileFilter: [getDescription: {-> "*.xls"}, accept:{file -> file.toString() ==~ /.*?\.xls/  || file.isDirectory() }] as FileFilter`

[ Win7(x64) Groovy Version: 1.8.3 JVM: 1.6.0_29) ]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a SwingBuilder object first. This worked for me:

```
def swing = new SwingBuilder()
def dialog = swing.fileChooser(dialogTitle: "Open A File")
if (dialog.showOpenDialog() == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    println dialog.selectedFile
}
```

Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for a complete list of properties.